# How to extract the text from certain places in the file?

Tags: r, text

Here is my data:

text <- **9 Mr.ABCD. Content1. Mrs. DEFG.Content2. **8 Mr.DBC something else. Content3.

How can I get data frame with as below:

9  Mr.  ABCD. Content1
9  Mrs.  DEFG. Content2
8  Mr.  DBC.  Content3

3 rows, 4 variables (number, Mr./Mrs., name, content)

The names in my data are always after Mr. or Mrs., and always in uppercases. There is alway a period before the content that I wanted.

Generally speaking I want to know who said what (with the number label)

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

We may do

```
library(stringr)
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)
tibble(col1 = text) %>% 
   separate_rows(col1, sep = "(?<=Content\\d\\.)\\s+") %>% 
   mutate(grp = readr::parse_number(col1)) %>%
   fill(grp) %>% 
   mutate(col1 = str_c(grp, str_remove(col1, "^[*]+\\d+\\s*"),
            sep=" "), grp = NULL) %>%
    pull(col1)
```

-output

```
[1] "9 Mr.ABCD. Content1."               "9 Mrs. DEFG.Content2."              "8 Mr.DBC something else. Content3."
```

#### data

```
text <- "**9 Mr.ABCD. Content1. Mrs. DEFG.Content2. **8 Mr.DBC something else. Content3."
```